# Accessing string elements of a list

Tags: python, string, list, web-scraping, iteration

Let's say I have a list and I want to access all items of the list which is a string and in the item, I want to access till a specific element how will I do that. The list is given below it is data scraped from Flipkart.

```
['₹237₹1,59985% off\nOr Pay ₹225 + \n 12',
 '₹570₹79928% off\nOr Pay ₹541 + \n 29',
 '₹621₹79922% off\nOr Pay ₹589 + \n 32',
 '₹299₹2,59988% off',
 '₹237₹1,59985% off\nOr Pay ₹225 + \n 12',
 '₹331₹1,59979% off\nOr Pay ₹314 + \n 17',
 '₹733₹89918% off\nOr Pay ₹696 + \n 37',
 '₹674₹89925% off\nOr Pay ₹640 + \n 34',
 '₹331₹2,59987% off\nOr Pay ₹314 + \n 17',
 '₹213₹1,19982% off',
 '₹281₹1,99985% off',
 '₹237₹1,59985% off\nOr Pay ₹225 + \n 12',
 '₹404₹1,99979% off',
 '₹249₹99975% off',
 '₹199₹99980% off',
 '₹499₹2,25677% off',
 '₹246₹1,49983% off\nOr Pay ₹233 + \n 13',
 '₹156₹75079% off',
 '₹399₹1,99980% off',
 '₹251₹1,19979% off',
 '₹399₹1,99980% off',
 '₹252₹1,49983% off',
 '₹319₹1,49978% off',
 '₹349₹1,19970% off',
 '₹217₹99978% off',
 '₹214₹69969% off',
 '₹499₹2,22577% off',
 '₹399₹1,49973% off',
 '₹282₹1,14575% off',
 '₹1,085₹1,29916% off\nOr Pay ₹1,030 + \n 55',
 '₹209₹99979% off',
 '₹210₹1,46685% off',
 '₹449₹2,22579% off',
 '₹265₹1,29979% off',
 '₹227₹78571% off',
 '₹199₹99980% off',
 '₹319₹1,99884% off',
 '₹449₹1,99577% off',
 '₹449₹1,99977% off',
 '₹249₹59958% off']
```

From the above list I want to get outputs from each item like ₹449, where I want to get the elements before the second rupee symbol for example from an : '₹1,085₹1,29916% off\nOr Pay ₹1,030 + \n 55' ; item I want ₹1,085.

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: You can use a regular expression inside a list comprehension.

Comment: ```x=input("Enter Price: ")```, then ```d=[xy[len("₹"+x):] for xy in l1 if xy.startswith("₹"+x)]``` if you don't want the initial price or ```d=[xy for xy in l1 if xy.startswith("₹"+x)]```

Comment: try this   -->  ["₹"+x.split("₹")[1] for x in a]                where a=[...] the list with your values

Answer (score 0):

I hope the below sample code can satisfy your use case -

```
my_list=['₹237₹1,59985% off\nOr Pay ₹225 + \n 12',
 '₹570₹79928% off\nOr Pay ₹541 + \n 29',
 '₹621₹79922% off\nOr Pay ₹589 + \n 32',
 '₹299₹2,59988% off',
 '₹237₹1,59985% off\nOr Pay ₹225 + \n 12',
 '₹331₹1,59979% off\nOr Pay ₹314 + \n 17',
 '₹733₹89918% off\nOr Pay ₹696 + \n 37',
 '₹674₹89925% off\nOr Pay ₹640 + \n 34',
 '₹331₹2,59987% off\nOr Pay ₹314 + \n 17',
 '₹213₹1,19982% off',
 '₹281₹1,99985% off',
 '₹237₹1,59985% off\nOr Pay ₹225 + \n 12',
 '₹404₹1,99979% off',
 '₹249₹99975% off',
 '₹199₹99980% off',
 '₹499₹2,25677% off',
 '₹246₹1,49983% off\nOr Pay ₹233 + \n 13',
 '₹156₹75079% off',
 '₹399₹1,99980% off',
 '₹251₹1,19979% off',
 '₹399₹1,99980% off',
 '₹252₹1,49983% off',
 '₹319₹1,49978% off',
 '₹349₹1,19970% off',
 '₹217₹99978% off',
 '₹214₹69969% off',
 '₹499₹2,22577% off',
 '₹399₹1,49973% off',
 '₹282₹1,14575% off',
 '₹1,085₹1,29916% off\nOr Pay ₹1,030 + \n 55',
 '₹209₹99979% off',
 '₹210₹1,46685% off',
 '₹449₹2,22579% off',
 '₹265₹1,29979% off',
 '₹227₹78571% off',
 '₹199₹99980% off',
 '₹319₹1,99884% off',
 '₹449₹1,99577% off',
 '₹449₹1,99977% off',
 '₹249₹59958% off']
 
 
result_list=[]
for element in my_list:
    for i in range(1,len(element)-1):
        if(element[i]=='₹'):
            result_list.append(element[0:i])
            break
print(result_list)
```